# Screen resolution is the same on AndroidTV box for all tv devices and monitors

Tags: android, display, android-tv, screen-size

I`m developing some AndroidTV application for AndroidTV boxes. And I have noticed the very strange moment. If I try to get programmatically screen width and height

```
val width = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
val height = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
```

then these two values will be the same for all tv and all monitor (for one tv box) to which my tv box was attached. For example, on my xiaomi mi box 4 I obtain **always** screen resolution 1920x1080 and it does not matter, does TV have 4k resolution or does some monitor have 1280 × 720.
And it is so  strange and I did not understand, why it happens. How can I obtain real width and height of my screen in AndroidTV app? Maybe, there are some another methods for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try that code, it gets the dimensions in pixels:

```
  val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
  val windowsManager =
applicationContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
  windowsManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
  val deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
  val deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
```

source:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels-on-android-app-using-kotlin